# timepicker not working in IE 11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am using this [timepicker](https://github.com/perifer/timePicker).its working fine in all browsers(including IE9,10) except IE11 only not working properly on time selection in the dropdown. how to resolve this

Comment: Any more information you  can provide might help in a solution.  errors, console logs etc

Comment: The lib was last updated 4 years ago, so its likely that it never supported ie11. if you have errors please post them along with the code you are using to implement timepicker